# Typescript: How to define types for factory functions returning literal objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following function:

```
const ServerRequest = ({ token: ServerRequestOptions }) => ({
  async() {}
})
```

and I'm not able to use the `ServerRequest` as a directly type on my `AuthService` because it is a function so, I have to do some "tricks" like:

```
const AuthService = (request: ReturnType<typeof ServerRequest>) => ({ })
```

For me this trick does not sound good because to use a simple reference to the ServerRequest I have to compose some "complex" types. I also tried to export it as a diff type:

```
type ServerRequestType = ReturnType<typeof ServerRequest>
```

But I see many naming conventions saying to "never" use pre/postfix like `I`, `Interface`, `Type`, etc.

So, what should be the best path for this case?

Comment: I'd suggest that `ServerRequest` isn't an appropriate name for a factory function, it should be `makeServerRequest` or similar. Then you can define a type for what it returns (perhaps `ServerRequest` :-) ) and use that type where necessary.

Comment: Yes, naming is definitely confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need type which defines function signature.

```js
interface ServerRequestOptions {/* ...*/}

// Proper function signature
type ServerRequestFunc = (options: {token: ServerRequestOptions}) => void;

// variable holding function
const serverRequest: ServerRequestFunc = ({ token: ServerRequestOptions }) => ({
  async() {}
})

const authService = (request: ServerRequestFunc ) => ({ })

authService(serverRequest); // works fine.
```

Or even simpler,if we add name to our input parameter of `serverRequest`:

```js
const serverRequest = (options: { token: string }) => ({
  async() {}
})

const authService = (request: typeof serverRequest) => ({ })

authService(serverRequest); // also works
```

Only, in 2nd example intellisense is not pretty (ex: hover over `authService` function in IDE).